# getting out of angular 4 change detection for some reason

Tags: angular

i've written a small directive to wrap CanadaPost AddressComplete script (which is actually a PostalCodeAnywhere PCA js script). Everything seems to be working except that i fall out of ng 4 change detection and have to manually trigger it. I wonder if there is anything wrong with my code and if there is a better way to handle this.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer, Output, Input, AfterViewInit, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';
import { Address } from './address';

declare var pca: any;

@Directive({
  selector: "[acAddressComplete]",
  providers: [NgModel]
})
export class AddressCompleteDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  @Output() setAddress: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  private addressComplete: any;
  private el: HTMLElement;

  constructor(private element: ElementRef, private model: NgModel, private renderer: Renderer) {
    this.el = element.nativeElement;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    //id of the input we attach to is set dynamically, so we have to wait till view is initialized
    this.addressComplete = new pca.Address([{ element: this.el.id, mode: pca.fieldMode.SEARCH }],
      {
        key: "xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx",
        suppressAutocomplete: true
      });

    this.addressComplete.listen("populate", (address) => {
      this.setAddress.emit(address);
    });
  }

}
```

So directive is emitting the event on address population.
This is the parent component:

```
    import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output, ChangeDetectorRef, ViewChild, ViewChildren, 
             Renderer, ElementRef, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
    import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
    import { SelectItem } from 'primeng/primeng';
    import { Address } from './address';
    import { AddressCompleteDirective } from './address-complete.directive';

    @Component({
        selector: 'address',
        templateUrl: 'address.component.html'
    })
    export class AddressComponent {
        @Input() addressCompleteId: string;
        @ViewChild(AddressCompleteDirective) addressComplete: AddressCompleteDirective;
        @Output() onAddressPopulated = new EventEmitter<Address>();
        @ViewChildren('addressField') addressFields: QueryList<ElementRef>;

        constructor(private renderer: Renderer, private translateService: TranslateService, private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
        }

        address = new Address();

        getAddress(address: any) {
            this.addressLabel = address.Label;

            this.address.city = address.City;
            this.address.streetNum = address.BuildingNumber;
            this.address.addressLine = address.Street;
            this.address.unitNum = address.SubBuilding;
            this.address.region = address.Province;
            this.address.postCode = address.PostalCode;

            // we need to do this here as it is out of angular zone for some reason
            // we need both of these to force detection check to run and mark all elements in this cmp
            this.ref.markForCheck();
            this.ref.detectChanges();

            this.addressFields.forEach(element => {
                this.renderer.setElementClass(element.nativeElement, 'ui-state-filled', true);
            });
        }
    }
```

And this is the template for address complete input:

```
<input id={{addressCompleteId}} name="addressComplete" type="text" size="30" pInputText (setAddress)="getAddress($event)" acAddressComplete>
```

And the field that will be populated with city:

```
<input #addressField name="city" type="text" size="30" [(ngModel)]="address.city" pInputText >
```

I'm using primeng InputText components as well.

So the issue is that unless i force manually change detection (see markForCheck/detectChanges above), the values in the form (e.g. city) are not updated immediately but only after focus change (mouse click). And i also had to manually set primeng class for floating label to update.

i wonder if there is a better way. The way i put it doesn't look right to me :(

Comment: I see you have `@Output() onAddressPopulated = new EventEmitter<Address>();`, but... I don't see you using it?

Comment: Change detection doesn't needed.

Comment: i use it in upper level component. here i use setAddress